# Error when trying to read to read from Entry

Tags: python, tkinter

First of all I'd like to make clear that I'm a rookie and that I know this is probably the wrong way to write this (with the exec() statements) but I couldn't index them so this was the solution I came up with and if you have an alternative I'd be happy to change the code.

But the clumsy way of defining my tables is not the reason I'm here (or maybe it is because I could easily have made a mistake because of it).
When I try to run this code everything goes well until the last part. I get an error message saying: '_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!entry"' and I have no idea what it is and how to solve it.

My program needs to read a set amount of colors which is given by max_number_of_colors and save it in a list

This is the piece of code I'm talking about:

```
def get_entry_colors():
    global all_colors
    all_colors = []
    for i in range(1,max_number_of_colors+1):
        exec('all_colors['+str(i-1)+'] = int(E'+str(i)+'.get())')
    return
def get_colors(max_number_of_colors):
    """
     #define max_number_of_color fields with the same amount of entry boxes
    """
    global setup
    setup = Tk()
    setup.title("Mastermind - setup")
    for i in range(1,max_number_of_colors+1):
        exec('global E'+str(i))
    for i in range(1,max_number_of_colors+1):
        exec('label'+str(i)+' = Label(setup, text="color'+str(i)+':");E'+str(i)+' = Entry(setup, bd=5)')
    #define button
    submit = Button(setup, text='Submit', command=get_entry_colors)
    #draw the fields and entry boxes
    for i in range(1,max_number_of_colors+1):
        exec("label" + str(i) + ".pack();E" + str(i) + ".pack()")
    #draw button
    submit.pack(side=BOTTOM)
    setup.mainloop()
```

Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: You should forget `exec` exists. Store your data in lists and dictionaries and loop over them. Then your problems will resolve themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrote this for you without using `exec` and without making arbitrary variables. Don't do that anymore. If you have a series of things to store, use a single instance of a container type like a list or a dictionary.

```
import Tkinter as tk

def get_entry_colors():
    all_colors = []
    for i in entry_list:
        all_colors.append(i.get())
    print(all_colors)

def get_colors(max_number_of_colors):
    """
     #define max_number_of_color fields with the same amount of entry boxes
    """
    global entry_list
    entry_list = []

    setup = tk.Tk()
    setup.title("Mastermind - setup")

    for i in range(1,max_number_of_colors+1):
        lbl = tk.Label(setup, text="color {}:".format(i))
        lbl.pack()
        ent = tk.Entry(setup, bd=5)
        ent.pack()
        entry_list.append(ent)
    #define button
    submit = tk.Button(setup, text='Submit', command=get_entry_colors)

    submit.pack()
    setup.mainloop()

get_colors(5)
```

Using `global` is somewhat bad too; you should try to get out of that habit.

Comment: Thank you. Really appreciated. I couldn't figure out how to create a list with label and entry. This helps a lot!